# Copy and Paste a row with many attributes into new features in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a feature class I just added a few features and I would like to copy and paste the whole row from existing feature to the new features. 
As I have many attributes and features, using copy and paste is very time consuming and using join and field calculator is also very time consuming as I have too many attributes. 
Is there a way to copy whole row and paste to another row. Or should I try SearchCursor. I am not very familiar with Python but I will to try if SearchCursor can do the work. 
I am using ArcMap 10.4.

Comment: Do you want to copy features within the same feature class, or from one feature class to the other? Also, consider using default values for new features, if the attributes are identical or almost identical

Comment: I added a few features from other feature class but the schema are totally different thus the new features have null value for all the attributes. I want to copy the attributes from a row within the same feature class and paste them in the new features added.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand clearly what you're doing. Maybe you could select all features whose attributes need to be calculated, then run Calculate Field. It will populate one field at a time, but for all features at once.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. I can do Calculate Field but I have like more than 80 fields. I am only adding 1 or 2 feature at a time that is why I am trying to copy the fields in a row and pasting them into the new added features.

Comment: An `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` certainly could work, but only in conjunction with an `InsertCursor`. Please focus your question on one of these two approaches: if you go the cursor route, you'll need to attemp a solution first. The documentation examples are good, and it's not particularly difficult.

Comment: If you only have a few records at a time you might look at using the Spatial Adjustment - Attribute Transfer tool to copy the entire attributes from the old to a new feature.  If you have a lot of records you could see if you could do a join on them, export the results to a new feature class/shapefile, remove the join and then add the new features to your layer.

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve this without using Python might be the [Attribute Transfer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/editing-existing-features/transferring-attributes-between-features.htm) on the Spatial Adjustment Toolbar. You would set your source and target layers to be the same. In an edit session, just click on the feature with the attributes then the other feature without attributes. Your target feature will have the same attributes as your source feature.